# Toggle visibility div not scrolling on iphone

Tags: javascript, html, css, iphone, scroll

I'm using code from this website:  http://blog.movalog.com/a/javascript-toggle-visibility/

The problem is when the text gets too long the toggle div won't scroll on an iphone.  The content gets cut off.  If I try scrolling the content under the toggle div moves but not the fixed div on top.  How do I make it so the toggle div scrolls when it is activated?

Here is the link to my issue:  http://www.jillmark.com/pslafinal/Healthcare/peace-labyrinth.html#

I have tried researching various solutions.  The most logical one seems to be making the fixed div have overflow-y:scroll; and height:100%;  but that didn't work.  Hoping it is something simple I'm missing.  I appreciate the help.

```js
     
function toggle_visibility(id) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   if(e.style.display == 'block')
      e.style.display = 'none';
   else
      e.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
.portfolio-sliver {
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:235px; /*compensates for 15px padding on col*/
    width:100%;
    height:50px; 
    background:#fff;
    padding-top:2px;
}
.portfolio-sliver #foo {
    position:fixed;
    top:150px;
    height:auto;
    width:350px;
    background-color:#efefef;
    z-index:1000;
    padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio-sliver">
    <h4>
        <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('foo');">peace labyrinth +</a>
    </h4>
    <div id="foo" style="display:none;">
        <p>really long text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: With `height: auto` `#foo` will be resized based on its content. Another thing is that you have used `position: fixed` which is *always* positioned relative to the screen's viewport. Try using: `position: absolute; top: 48px;`

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the problem with the given code. Please post a JSfiddle of your code, demonstrating the problem

Comment: This is my first jsfiddle attempt.  I want the #foo div to open when clicked otherwise it is hidden.  It does this on my website but not in the fiddle.  Here is the link to fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jmark4/zwe5nrrk/3/

Comment: The link to the problem on my website is the following:  http://www.jillmark.com/pslafinal/Healthcare/peace-labyrinth.html#.  The #foo div content gets cutoff when viewing on iphone.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: Changing the `position:fixed` to `position:absolute` worked great!  Simple fix.  Thank you @Green